# .NET get data from printers which have www interface

Tags: c++, .net, sockets, networking, network-printers

I would like to get data about ink, free pages (paper) etc from the printers in company network. Each of these printers (mostly Minolta) has an www interface, so I can get these data by creating browser process in my program, direct it to go to the address  "http://192.168.X.YY/data.htm", download all the page code and retrieve the data from it. Is this possible without this process? If I know that these data are under each IP/data.htm can I use this information to download data in the different way: socket, ftp, etc.

In general: if you have some data on the website (no database access obviously), how you retrieve this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, your printer provides REST-based services. You can use [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) to make REST based API calls. (This holds for most websites also!)

Comment: The OP specifically mentioned .NET twice, so I think [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) or something similar would be more appropriate.

Comment: True. He also mentions C++, so I provided libcurl which also does have a .NET binding. BTW: This printer related data fetch is something we do on fairly regular basis and libcurl + C++ can save you a lot of trouble when distributing.

Comment: I suspect that was a naive attempt at saying C++/CLI though. :-] It's hard to tell either way when there's no code...

Comment: ok, so I have advices: REST, libcurl and HttpWebRequest. Probably I will try to use this libcurl as it is written in C++. thanks you all guys.

Comment: btw: shouldn't it be also possible by a socket application?

Comment: @cf16: That really depends on your data server. If it allows you to hook up using sockets and make specific calls, you can. But that wouldn't exactly be making REST API calls.

Comment: You could use raw sockets and make your own HTTP client but that's not recommended :)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound like it implements a REST interface from the description you provided.

It sounds like your idea is to scrape data from an HTML page.  That's fine too, although it's somewhat fragile (e.g. could break with a printer firmware upgrade).

Anyway, you tagged the question with .NET so if you want to use the .NET approach, you might want to look at creating a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) and parsing the resulting data return from the `DownloadString` method.

Comment: If you can find a REST-ful interface, it'll make your life easier

Comment: yes, thanks, I've forgot that there is no need to call browser when .NET.WebClient is created, just downloadData, or downloadString then. I know the drawbacks of the approach, do you think there exists another way to interact with these data? In my opinion it would be desirable if these printers make data accessible in some different way.

Comment: I'm not sure about the printer API.  It wouldn't shock me either way if they did/did not expose a nice REST interface